# If all the critical values are shown in the chart below...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is a strange question:

If all the critical values of f(x) are shown below in the chart, which of the following could be values for f'(x) at x=1.5,2.5 and 3.5?
CHART:

x: 1, 2, 3, 4

f'(x): 0.5, 3, -5, -5

Answer choices:

1) 
x: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

f'(x): 3, -7, 2

2) 
x: 1.5, 2.5 , 3.5

f'(x): 2, -4, -2

3) 
x: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

f'(x): 2.5, -8, -3

4) 
x: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

f'(x): -2, -4, 2

5) 
x: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

f'(x): -2, -4, -2

I thought that for there to be a critical value, f(x) = 0. So shouldn't f'(x) be zero at 1, 2, 3 and 4? Can someone help me?

Comment: The derivative may also be undefined at a critical point. But you are right, the question seems completely off. Perhaps they meant the second line contains values of $f(x)$ rather than $f'(x)$.

Comment: If that is the case, would the answer be the first one? Because I'm winging it.